# Parsing XML JQuery Ajax Response with Namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm executing a web service call using JQuery and it's ajax function and I'm unable to parse the data coming back.  When I alert the data (alert($(data).find("return").text()) its empty.  I see the server responding with xml data as outlined below and when I alert(data) I get [object XMLDocument].  Is txt = $(data).find("return").text() valid given my XML structure with a namespace below?  I can see the full xml string in firebug. Any ideas?

var txt = $(data).find("ns1\:return").text(); works on Chrome and Firefox, but not Safari

**index.js:**

```
$(function () {
$.ajax({
                url: url,
                success: function (data) {
                    var ndx = 0,
                        row,
                        **txt = $(data).find("return").text(),**
                        xml = unescape(txt),
                        xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
                        firstrow = $(xmlDoc).find(
                                "results").children(":first");

                    // populate the table based on the results returned by
                    // the web service
                    $("table.results thead").empty();
                    $("table.results tbody").empty();
                    row = $("<tr/>");

                    row.append($("<th/>").text("#").addClass("ndx"));
                    firstrow.children().each(function () {
                        row.append($("<th/>").text(this.nodeName));
                    });
                    row.appendTo($("table.results thead"));

                    $(xmlDoc).find("row").each(function () {
                        row = $("<tr/>");
                        row.append($("<td/>").text(ndx + 1).addClass("ndx"));
                        $(this).children().each(function () {
                            row.append($("<td/>").text($(this).text()));
                        });
                        row.appendTo($("table.results tbody"));
                        ndx++;
                    });

                    // clear the table if no results were returned
                    if (ndx == 0) {
                        // no rows returned
                        $("table.results thead").empty();
                        $("table.results tbody").empty();
                    }

                    statusNotice("Records Returned: " + ndx);
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // display the error returned by the web service
                    var xmlDoc = $(XMLHttpRequest.responseXML);
                    statusError(xmlDoc.find("Text").text());
                },          
                complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
                    // hide the busy dialog
                    $("#busy-dlg").dialog("close");
                }
            });
       });
```

**index.html:**
    
    
    
    
    Demo

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.layout-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
//table displaying results from ajax call here
</body>
</html>
```

**XML:**

```
<ns1:executeResponse xmlns:ns1="http://sqlws.test.com">
<ns1:return>
    <results>
        <row>
            <attribute1>value1</attribute1>
            <attribute2>value2</attribute2>
        </row>
        <row>
            <attribute1>value1</attribute1>
            <attribute2>value2</attribute2>
        </row>
    </results>
</ns1:return>
</ns1:executeResponse>
```

Comment: The XML structure is invalid, `<attribute1>` does not match `</atribute1>` (missing `t` in the closing tag).

Comment: @RobW - that was a typo fixed now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When an element is prefixed by a namespace, you **have** to also add the namespace:

- `.find('ns1:return')` does not work, because `:` is used by jQuery as pseudo-selectors.
- `.find('ns1\:return')` does not work either, because a single backslash in a string is used as an escape character. `"ns1\:return"` becomes `"ns1:return"` which is equal to the previous one.
- **`.find('ns1\\:return')`** should be used. The double backslash is used to escape the colon.

It appears that the last solution works fine in IE and Firefox, but not Opera, Chrome or Safari. To get maximum compatibility, use jQuery selectors with, and without fake prefix, ie. `"ns1\\:return, return"` instead of a plain `ns1\\:return`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5BQjv/51/

```
// For example, this is the result:
var data = '<ns1:executeResponse xmlns:ns1="http://sqlws.test.com">' +
               '<ns1:return>' + 
                   '<results> <row> ... </row> </results>' +
               '</ns1:return>' +
           '</ns1:executeResponse>';

// The very first thing is to parse the string as XML. NOT later!
var $xmlDoc = $($.parseXML(data));

// Then, look for the element with the namespace:
var $txt = $xmlDoc.find('ns1\\:return, return');

// No need to use unescape or something, just use DOM manipulation:
// `results` is the immediate child. Don't use .find, but .children
var $firstrow = $txt.children("results").children(":first");
```

As you may have noticed, I have prefixed some variables with a dollar sign. It's the convention to prefix variables which refer to jQuery objects with a dollar sign, to avoid confusion during/after development.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you for saving me from hours of probably-fruitless mucking around.

Comment: This is awesome, but fake.  What your solution does is query on namespace PREFIXES, which is not the same as namespace. `ns1` is the prefix, and in your case it refers to the namespace `http://sqltest.test.com`.  So far I haven't seen any solution that actually correctly deals with namespaces, only answers that show how to deal with namespace prefixes. The problem is when the doc formatting  gets changed, the namespace prefixes may change (or may be ABSENT completely) and yet the doc is completely equivalent from an XML infoset perspective.

Comment: @dizel3d Updated answer and tested against other browsers.