# How can I handle XML namespaces in CSS Selectors or in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, xml-namespaces

I use jQuery to parse an RSS feed. I can successfully get the RSS feed using AJAX:

```
$.get("podcast.xml", function (data) {
    xml = $(data);
}, "xml");
```

Now I can get the title of the podcast by using `xml.find("channel > title").text()`. How can I select the `<itunes:image>` tag in my RSS feed?

The command `xml.find("channel > itunes:image")` does not work, because `:` separates in CSS the tag name and the pseudo class. I also tried `xml.find("channel > image")` but it does not work.

How can I handle XML namespaces in CSS Selectors or in jQuery?

Comment: Use `\\:` (escaped `:`): `xml.find("channel > itunes\\:image")`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing XML JQuery Ajax Response with Namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625487/parsing-xml-jquery-ajax-response-with-namespace)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CSS allows you to specify [namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-namespace) for use with [selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selector-syntax) within stylesheets.

However, jQuery doesn't support this since you have no way of declaring the XML namespace in the first place (as jQuery has nothing to do with CSS besides borrowing from its selector syntax), so you have to treat the colon as a literal character instead by escaping it like so:

```
xml.find("channel > itunes\\:image")
```

Answer (score 4):

I want to add something wired I just explored: If I try the above code on my rekonq browser (which uses webkit), I cannot find the `<itunes:image>` tag by searching for `xml.find("channel > itunes\\:image")`.

I have to omit the term `itunes:` and have to type `xml.find("channel > image")`. So we have:

```
xml.find("channel > itunes\\:image") /* Firefox */

xml.find("channel > image") /* Rekonq (maybe also Safari and Chrome?!) */
```

Comment: I hadn't seen this answer, but I'd be damned if this wasn't another of WebKit's quirks. Either way, jQuery does not appear, nor claim, to support XML very well.