# With jQuery, how to find elements whose names have a particular substring

Tags: jquery

We have some HTML that has custom element names. I would like to build a jQuery selector that finds all elements whose names contain the substring 'xyz', for example. So in the DOM fragment:

```
<div>
  <fooxyzmore/>
</div>
```

The result would return the 'fooxyzmore' element.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the answer will be very similar of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17141209/4933917)

You just have to change the RegExp, the result would be

```
var results = $("div").find("*").filter(function(){     
     return /xyz/i.test(this.nodeName);
});
```

Hope it may helps you.

Comment: That is a fine solution, thank you. I was hoping, however, that there might be some selector syntax that would directly return the results. But at least there is a solution.
Thank you.