# JQuery find elements by partial tagname

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

I would like to find all elements on page by partial tagname.

For example, I would like to find all elements whose tagname contains the word `directive` using JQuery.

```
<a-directive>...</a-directive>
<directive-b>...</directive-b>
```

I tried `$("directive*")`, `$("*directive")`, `$("*directive*")` none of them worked for me.

I have only found a way in JQuery to find elements by partial attribute match, such as `$("[name*='something']")`

But could not find a way to find elements by partial tagname.

Comment: I request you to add a comment explaining what my question lacks before you downvote it. Thanks.

Comment: Two questions. 1) Why are you creating your own elements and b) what have you tried, and why the css-selectors tag?

Comment: @j08691 It is an aungular app, whose tag names contain the word `directive`, I would like to fetch them all for UI automation purposes.I tried different JQuery selectors that I am aware of and also searched online to select by partial tag name, could not find an answer, hence asked a question.

Comment: Are you sure there's no other angular-way for this UI automation stuff? Angular is not designed for direct DOM manipulation like with JQuery.

Comment: I downvoted because you gave us the problem but made no attempt to do it yourself.

Comment: @Sebastianb I am trying to run JS on page to check if all my desired elements on page have 'id'

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith May be I should have mentioned in my question what I have tried, but after all failed attempts is when I posted the question. Also I wanted to make the question short and to the point, I will make the necessary edits. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although jQuery has quite a [range of selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), I don't believe that they natively have support for targeting custom elements / tags.

Because of this, you would likely need to implement your own approach similar to the recommendation mentioned in [this related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17141209/557445) :

```
// Terribly inefficient approach (scope to parent element if at all possible
var directives = $("*").filter(function(){
      // Return any elements that contains directive as the node name
      return /^.*directive.*$/i.test(this.nodeName);
});
```

**Example**

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a-directive>A</a-directive>
  <div>Not A Directive</div>
  <directive-b>B</directive-b>
  <script>
    $(function(){
        var $directives = $("*").filter(function(){
          // Return any elements that contains directive as the node name
          return /^.*directive.*$/i.test(this.nodeName);
        });
        // Color your directives
        $directives.css('color','red');
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to create a custom selector using jQuery:

```
(function( $ ) {

     function icontains(elem, tagName) {
         return elem.nodeName.toLowerCase().indexOf((tagName || "").toLowerCase() ) > -1;
     }

     $.expr.pseudos.tagNameContains = $.expr.createPseudo ?
     $.expr.createPseudo(function( tagName ) {
        return function(elem) {
            return icontains(elem, tagName);
        };
     }) :

     function(elem, i, match) {
         return icontains(elem, match[3]);
     };

})(jQuery);
```

Then, you would use it like this:

```
//searches entire DOM for elements with 'directive' in tag name
$(':tagNameContains(directive)')
```

or

```
//searches under div.someClass for elements with 'directive' in tag name
$('div.someClass :tagNameContains(directive)')
```

[Source](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki#-backwards-compatible-plugins-for-pseudos-with-arguments)