# jQuery select <tr> with custom attribute that contains ":"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select rows using jQuery and make their background colour red or green based on a condition but I can't seem to get jQuery to select them.
I can only identify them by a unique INT number in a custom attribute.

The HTML looks like this

```
<tr df:row_id="0" ..........
```

I tried N variants of code like

```
$("[df:row_id='"+theId+"']").css({ 'background-color' : 'green'});
```

or

```
$("tr[df:row_id='"+theId+"']").css({ 'background-color' : 'green'});
```

and variations using either simple or double quotes but I can't seem to get it right. I keep getting

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: tr df:row_id='0'

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [df:row_id='0']
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:` is a special character in selector syntax, you will need to escape it:

```
$("tr[df\\:row_id='"+theId+"']").css({ 'background-color' : 'green'});
```

(Normally, this is a `row_id` attribute in the `df` XML namespace, but [jQuery does not support XML DOMs or namespaced selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502641/how-can-i-handle-xml-namespaces-in-css-selectors-or-in-jquery/11502677#11502677) so it is acceptable to simply escape the `:`.)

Answer (score 1):

You should use escape character identifier **`\\`** to archive this,

```
$("tr[df\\:row_id='"+theId+"']").css({ 'background-color' : 'green'});
```

#### View Static demo <kbd>**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ug9cgj5/)**</kbd>

```
$("tr[df\\:row_id='1']").css({ 'background-color' : 'green'});
```