# Wouldn't display image on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, web

I have a page.... http://kingola.com/test.html that i'm working on for my mobile app, but for some reason, the image doesn't display on my Android mobile browser, but i see it on Firefox on my mac.

Also... for some reason it doesn't work in IE.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <title>Reading XML with jQuery</title>
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://kingola.com/podcast/",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
                        // var id = $(this).attr('guid');
                        var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                        var url = $(this).find("enclosure").attr('url');
                        var description = $(this).find('description').text();
                        var img = $(this).find("itunes\\:image").attr('href');
                        $('<div class="items" id="link_"></div>').html('<a href="'+url+'">'+title+'</a>').appendTo('#page-wrap');
                        $('<div class="brief"></div>').html(description).appendTo('#page-wrap');
                        $('<div class="image"></div>').html('<img src="'+img+'">').appendTo('#page-wrap');
                        $('<div class="ima-link"></div>').html(img).appendTo('#page-wrap');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page-wrap">
        <h1>Reading XML with jQuery</h1>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean image does not display? Is it that the image is not loaded at all or is it that it is loaded but the image source is broken? When I see your demo, none of the images are loading in Chrome Mac.

Comment: The image does not display. It should be loaded. Test on Firefox to see.

Comment: Got it to work.
Thanks guys.

This helped. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625487/parsing-xml-jquery-ajax-response-with-namespace

Answer (score 0):

Your source is not being defined there for not showing, could you try this

```
$('<div class="image"></div>').html('<img src="'+img+'">').appendTo($("#page-wrap"));
```

Answer (score 0):

the variable of img is undefined,because the selector of the node is wrong,try this

```
var img = $(this).find("image").attr('href');
```

because the name of the node of  is image, the itunes is the namespace of these nodes

Comment: Also fixed, but now none of them works. Not even Firefox which used to be the only one that worked.

Comment: Works on Safari & Mobile now, but image doesnt display on Firefox and IE is still just blank. :(